# How To add TextBoxes Data in asp.net using Onblur event

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a ASP.net web application where i need to add different text boxes data and save it in another text box .But using java Script and onblur event. How can we do please say in clear and understanding way because am new to It.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery's blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$('#TextBox1').blur(function() {
  alert('Handler for .blur() called.');
});
```

To expand on this and do some calculation/set the value of another textbox we could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[id$=TextBox1]").blur(function() {
           $("input[id$=TextBox2]").val('Some text')
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Seany84 thanks for the Reply . but actually i need to be do it in JavaScript only and i got it once again thanks

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript.. I downvoted this for not specifying that in the original question.